# Getting Cannot convert to Xamarin.Forms.Element error when trying to create custom ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to separate styles into multiple ResourceDictionary files.  According to the documentation, I should create a content view or content page and change it to inherit from ResourceDictionary.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries

> To create such a file, add a new Content View or Content Page item to the project (but not a Content View or Content Page with only a C# file). In both the XAML file and C# file, change the name of the base class from ContentView or ContentPage to ResourceDictionary. In the XAML file, the name of the base class is the top-level element.

I'm getting a compile error:

> Cannot convert from MyApp1.Themes.RedTheme to Xamarin.Forms.Element

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <themes:ThemeBlue></themes:ThemeBlue>
            <themes:ThemeRed></themes:ThemeRed>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

RedTheme.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp1.Themes.RedTheme"
         x:Name="redtheme">

    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"></Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

RedTheme.xaml.cs

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class RedTheme : ResourceDictionary
{
    public RedTheme()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
}
```

Does this not work in Visual Studio?  There is also no ResouceDictionary template in the add new file menu in Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you getting the compile error when compiling App.xaml or RedTheme.xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML File template can be used:

Add New Item > Installed > Visual C# Items > Data > XML File

App.xaml [merged `ResourceDictionary` in Xamarin.Forms 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#merged-resource-dictionaries):

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionary.xaml" />
    ...
```

MyResourceDictionary.xaml, no [`.xaml.cs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#merging-dictionaries-in-xamarinforms-30) needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    ...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add x:key on your style. That's why you getting that exception.